# Communication error with Jack server (77) causing Jenkins build to fail

Tags: jenkins, android

I am creating a CI build for compiling our custom Android ROM / OS and I am receiving an odd error in Jenkins when trying to do an automated build. The issue doesn't take place when I build manually which leaves me to believe that it's related to Jenkins but I can't seem to figure out why.

From researching around it seems that many people have an issue with the jackserver that is memory related, but the machine I'm building on has 64GB of RAM and 24 threads. Plus the error I am getting is a communication error:

```
Communication error with Jack server (77)
```

Below is the error log I am getting from Jenkins:

```
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin install-server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-launcher.jar prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.8.ALPHA.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0) ) && (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS=\"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation\" prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.8.ALPHA.jar 4.8.ALPHA 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-2.28.RELEASE.jar 2.28.RELEASE || exit 47; prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-3.36.CANDIDATE.jar 3.36.CANDIDATE || exit 47; prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-4.7.BETA.jar 4.7.BETA || exit 47 )"
Writing client settings in /nvme/jenkins-slave/.jack-settings
Installing jack server in "/nvme/jenkins-slave/.jack-server"

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /nvme/jenkins-slave/.jack-server/server.jks -destkeystore /nvme/jenkins-slave/.jack-server/server.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /nvme/jenkins-slave/.jack-server/client.jks -destkeystore /nvme/jenkins-slave/.jack-server/client.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
Communication error with Jack server (77), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log
Failed to contact Jack server: Problem reading /nvme/jenkins-slave/.jack-server/server.pem. Try 'jack-diagnose'
Failed to contact Jack server: Problem reading /nvme/jenkins-slave/.jack-server/server.pem. Try 'jack-diagnose'
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libandroidfw_32 <= frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/ResourceTypes.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libandroidfw_32 <= frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/StreamingZipInflater.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libandroidfw_32 <= frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/BackupData.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target SharedLib: libhardware_32 (out/target/product/rk3399_firefly_box/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libhardware_intermediates/LINKED/libhardware.so)
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libandroidfw_32 <= frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/ZipUtils.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libandroidfw_32 <= frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/BackupHelpers.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libandroidfw_32 <= frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/CursorWindow.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libandroidfw_32 <= frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/DisplayEventDispatcher.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libgui_32 <= frameworks/native/libs/gui/IGraphicBufferConsumer.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libgui_32 <= frameworks/native/libs/gui/IGraphicBufferProducer.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libgui_32 <= frameworks/native/libs/gui/IConsumerListener.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libgui_32 <= frameworks/native/libs/gui/BitTube.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] AAPT2 link out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-annotations_intermediates/package-res.apk
[ 31% 15431/48680] AAPT2 link out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-compat_intermediates/package-res.apk
[ 31% 15431/48680] AAPT2 link out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-fragment_intermediates/package-res.apk
[ 31% 15431/48680] AAPT2 link out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4_intermediates/package-res.apk
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libgui_32 <= frameworks/native/libs/gui/BufferItem.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libgui_32 <= frameworks/native/libs/gui/BufferItemConsumer.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libgui_32 <= frameworks/native/libs/gui/BufferQueue.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libgui_32 <= frameworks/native/libs/gui/BufferQueueConsumer.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libgui_32 <= frameworks/native/libs/gui/BufferQueueCore.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] target thumb C++: libcamera_client_32 <= frameworks/av/camera/Camera.cpp
[ 31% 15431/48680] Compiling SDK Stubs: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/classes.jar
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Another pain is that there is nothing logged in the Jackserver log files and when i run:

```
jack-diagnose
```

I am not getting anything of value. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super simple fix in the end, just needed to restart the server and my build is now completing.